# how to simplify this statement? php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i need to retrieve multiple selects from mysql table, my need is to simplify the statements

these are my statements

```
$stardate=dateselect
$enddate=dateselect

SELECT count(distinct(customer)) as customer FROM my_table where date_field BETWEEN'$startdate' AND '$enddate'
SELECT count(distinct(customer)) as computeris1 FROM my_table where computer=1 and date_field BETWEEN'$startdate' AND '$enddate'
SELECT count(distinct(customer)) as computeris2 FROM my_table where computer=2 and date_field BETWEEN'$startdate' AND '$enddate'
```

I have about 10 fields, each one has 4 or 5 values (choices) want to count the distinct customer for each field (e.g. computer) and all between 2 dates..

another problem is the date is a timestamp of mysql, doesn't return a correct and exclude today's records unless i select the end date as tomorrow then it works, i think it is a time issue, how i can make it count date correctly discarding the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the date/time problem by using `date()`.  As for the rest, you can use conditional aggregation to do everything in one query:

```
SELECT count(distinct(customer)) as customer,
       count(distinct case when computer = 1 then customer end) as computer1,
       count(distinct case when computer = 2 then customer end) as computer2
FROM my_table
where date(date_field) BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate';
```

This puts the values as separate columns rather than separate rows.